# How do non-human apes cool their body temperature in warm climates?

Tags: temperature, thermoregulation

Humans have sweat and we all know how that provides cooling along with the remaining vellus hairs acting as wicks.

So how do [hominids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hominidae), our close relatives (some of which are more massive than humans) regular their body temperature, given that they are completely covered in fur like typical mammals?

---

I’m specifically interested in how a human who had an [atavism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atavism)<sup>※</sup> that’s like [generalized hypertrichosis terminalis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertrichosis#Congenital) would fare and get by.

**※** in my story, it’s due to a *repaired* chromosome 17 that didn’t turn out the way that was intended.

Answer (score 1):

First they have less cooling needs than us, shady forests are cooler than sunlit savannah, they also are not as active, especially the larger ones, at least not in the hottest parts of the day. keep in mind chimps are much smaller than us so they have an easier time cooling off. They cool themselves the same way we do, by sweating, its just not s effective as it is in us, but then it doesn't need to be. .

Comment: Gorillas and urangs are larger than us.

Comment: hence needing to mention the chimps are smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the tactics include:
_ More frequent breaths.
_ Sweat more.
_ Loss of skin moisture.

You can read here for more details: https://physoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1113/jphysiol.1976.sp011251

Comment: Answers are expected to stand for themselves with references for further reading. It would be great if you could edit your answer with information from the paper you linked.